# A* heuristic for the game Blockage

Tags: a-star, heuristics

There is a flash game that you can very easily find on Google called **Blockage**.

> **Rules & Goal of the game** : Get all coloured blocks from
>   their initial position to a corresponding target spot of the same color. Once a block is placed on a target spot of the same color, it cannot move anymore. You can select a specific block and move it left or right. Blocks are also subject to gravity (moving them vertically until they hit a wall or another block). There can be many blocks of the same color and more blocks than target spots. Obstacles include walls and other blocks (two blocks cannot be at the same position).

To maybe get an idea of what it looks like, here's a picture of the initial state of one of the level of the game :

[image]

I would like to implement an **A* algorithm** that **finds the sequence of steps to win this game**.

I am currently **thinking** about a **good heuristic `h(n)`to use**. The best one I could find is the following : *the sum of the Manhattan distances between each colored block and its closest target*.

**Any idea on a better heuristic?**

Comment: Is this a good place for A*?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: It moves a block vertically until it hits a wall or another block.

Comment: OK, so those are "free moves", in a sense? Does that not make your current heuristic inadmissible?

Comment: Yes those are "free moves". For the heuristic, I am not sure. Why wouldn't it be admissible?

Comment: Because some moves are made by gravity, and you get them for free. Consider if there is 1 block, it's at the top and only needs to fall straight down. Cost: 0 moves. Manhattan distance would assign it a cost.

Comment: Oh yeah sure you're right! That now looks more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I think if we leave out vertical distance it'll be admissible, but clearly the heuristic is just getting worse now

Comment: What if we relax the problem by allowing the removal of the walls "on demand", the heuristic could be : the minimum between 1) the manhattan distance between block and goal and 2) the manhattan distance between block and goal once we let the block fall with gravity. Do you think it is good?

Comment: After thinking about it, the last one I suggested is not admissible neither. I am starting to think that there aren't lots of other possibilities than leaving out the vertical distance as you said...